# make a new thread service that start a connection and write to database

Tags: android, json, service, connection

i'm making some footsteps forward, but i have some problems, when i call the service, which should connect to a json resource, get the results and write them on the db, well... seams that nothing happen:

**the call:**

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(strdomanda), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    datasource.setRispostaSelezionata(Long.toString(id));   
    datasource.setDomandaFatta(strdomanda);
    datasource.close();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, updateDemocracyService.class);
    startService(intent);

    finish();



    }
```

**the service :**

```
public class updateDemocracyService extends IntentService{
    public updateDemocracyService() {
        super("updateDemocracyService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    private pollDataSource datasource;
     int mStartMode;       // indicates how to behave if the service is killed
        IBinder mBinder;      // interface for clients that bind
        boolean mAllowRebind; // indicates whether onRebind should be used
        // url to make request
        private static String url = "http://lnx.ggservice.com/democracy/domande.php";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_DOMANDE = "domande";
        private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
        private static final String TAG_TESTO = "testo";


        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray contacts = null;


        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            datasource = new pollDataSource(this);
            datasource.open();
            Thread t = new Thread(){
                public void run(){

            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {

                // Getting Array of Contacts
                contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DOMANDE);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_TESTO);
                    datasource.createCategoria(name);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                }
            };
            t.start();


            Toast.makeText(this,"faccio cose", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   


        }


}
```

the service probably start, i don't know how to check this, but indeed it does nothing, maybe it connect to the server, but most probably i'm mistaking something... do you see something wrong? why the service does nothing?
before this i was executing most of the code in the `onStartCommand`, but i see that i have to use `onHandleIntent`

**update:**

now it gives these errors:

```
01-03 09:28:39.582: D/dalvikvm(17584): GC_CONCURRENT freed 157K, 3% free 9328K/9607K, paused 13ms+15ms
01-03 09:28:40.162: W/dalvikvm(17584): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
01-03 09:28:40.242: E/AndroidRuntime(17584): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-124
01-03 09:28:40.242: E/AndroidRuntime(17584): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 09:28:40.242: E/AndroidRuntime(17584):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.releaseAndUnlock(SQLiteStatement.java:290)
01-03 09:28:40.242: E/AndroidRuntime(17584):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:115)
01-03 09:28:40.242: E/AndroidRuntime(17584):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
01-03 09:28:40.242: E/AndroidRuntime(17584):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
01-03 09:28:40.242: E/AndroidRuntime(17584):    at com.ggservice.democracy.pollDataSource.createCategoria(pollDataSource.java:41)
01-03 09:28:40.242: E/AndroidRuntime(17584):    at com.ggservice.democracy.updateDemocracyService$1.run(updateDemocracyService.java:63)
01-03 09:28:41.851: W/MessageQueue(17584): Handler (android.os.Handler) {412f6590} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
01-03 09:28:41.851: W/MessageQueue(17584): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {412f6590} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
01-03 09:28:41.851: W/MessageQueue(17584):  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:196)
01-03 09:28:41.851: W/MessageQueue(17584):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
01-03 09:28:41.851: W/MessageQueue(17584):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
01-03 09:28:41.851: W/MessageQueue(17584):  at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:263)
01-03 09:28:41.851: W/MessageQueue(17584):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.hide(Toast.java:358)
01-03 09:28:41.851: W/MessageQueue(17584):  at android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub.onTransact(ITransientNotification.java:55)
01-03 09:28:41.851: W/MessageQueue(17584):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
01-03 09:28:41.851: W/MessageQueue(17584):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

the datasource:

```
public class pollDataSource {
    // Database fields
      private SQLiteDatabase database;
      private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
      private String[] allCategorieColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
          MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PREF, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NOME };   
      private String[] allSondaggiColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
              MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CATID,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_WEBID,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FATTA, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DOMANDA };   
      private String[] allRisposteColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, 
              MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SONDID,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_WEBID, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_RISPOSTA, 
              MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SELEZIONATA };


      public pollDataSource(Context context) {
            dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
          }

      public void open() throws SQLException {
            database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
          }

      public void close() {
            dbHelper.close();
          }

      public categorie createCategoria(String categoria) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NOME, categoria);
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PREF, 0);
            long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE, null,
                values);
            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE,
                allCategorieColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            categorie newCategoria = cursorToCategorie(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return newCategoria;
          } 

      public void deleteCategoria(categorie categoria) {
            long id = categoria.getId();
            System.out.println("Categoria cancellata, id: " + id);
            database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID
                + " = " + id, null);
          }

      public sondaggi createSondaggio(String domanda, int catid, int webid) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DOMANDA, domanda);
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CATID, catid);
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_WEBID, webid);
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FATTA, "0");
            long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI, null,
                values);
            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI,
                allSondaggiColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            sondaggi newSondaggio = cursorToSondaggi(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return newSondaggio;
          }


      public void deleteSondaggio(sondaggi sondaggio) {
            long id = sondaggio.getId();
            System.out.println("Sondaggio cancellato, id: " + id);
            database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID
                + " = " + id, null);
          } 

      public Cursor getAllCategorie() {
            List<categorie> categorie = new ArrayList<categorie>();

            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE,
                allCategorieColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
              categorie categoria = cursorToCategorie(cursor);
              categorie.add(categoria);
              cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // Make sure to close the cursor
           // cursor.close();
            return cursor;
          }

      public Cursor getDomanda(String id) {
            List<sondaggi> domande = new ArrayList<sondaggi>();


            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI,
                    allSondaggiColumns,
                    MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                    new String[] { id }, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
              sondaggi sondaggio = cursorToSondaggi(cursor);
              domande.add(sondaggio);
              cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            return cursor;
          }


      private categorie cursorToCategorie(Cursor cursor) {
          categorie categorie = new categorie();
          categorie.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
          categorie.setPreferita(cursor.getLong(1));
          categorie.setNome(cursor.getString(2));
            return categorie;
          }


      private sondaggi cursorToSondaggi(Cursor cursor) {
          sondaggi sondaggi = new sondaggi();
          sondaggi.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
          sondaggi.setDomanda(cursor.getString(1));
          sondaggi.setCatid(cursor.getLong(2));
          sondaggi.setwebid(cursor.getLong(3));
          return sondaggi;
          }

    public Cursor getAllDomandeCategoria(String catid) {
        List<sondaggi> domande = new ArrayList<sondaggi>();


        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI,
                allSondaggiColumns,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CATID + "=? AND " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FATTA + "='0'",
                new String[] { catid }, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
          sondaggi sondaggio = cursorToSondaggi(cursor);
          domande.add(sondaggio);
          cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor getTestoRisposte(String strdomanda) {

        List<testo_risposte> domande = new ArrayList<testo_risposte>();    
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_TESTORISPOSTE,
                allRisposteColumns,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SONDID + "=?",
                new String[] { strdomanda }, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
         testo_risposte sondaggio = cursorToTestoRisposte(cursor);
          domande.add(sondaggio);
          cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        return cursor;
    }

    private testo_risposte cursorToTestoRisposte(Cursor cursor) {
        testo_risposte testo_risposte = new testo_risposte();
        testo_risposte.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        testo_risposte.setCatid(cursor.getLong(1));
        testo_risposte.setWebid(cursor.getLong(4));
        testo_risposte.Setselezionata(cursor.getLong(2));
        testo_risposte.setDomanda(cursor.getString(3));
     return testo_risposte;
    }

    public void setRispostaSelezionata(String id) {     
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SELEZIONATA, "1");
        database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_TESTORISPOSTE,values,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[] { id });    
    }

    public void setDomandaFatta(String strdomanda) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FATTA, "1");
        database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI,values,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[] { strdomanda });

    }


}
```

Comment: if you use an intent service, don't override so many things. for one, don't override onStartCommand, or call super.

Comment: ok, i try to clear it a bit, now i get only onHandleIntent and the costructor.

Comment: and call super.onDestroy() in onDestroy()

Comment: IT works, thanks, it's only a matter of clearness :D

Comment: adding the onDestroy gaves errors, but now, also if i delete it, i got some rrors, i edited the post.

Comment: one thing : onHandleIntent runs on a Thread, meaning you don't need to add your own. Also : is categoria (String) null ? in which case you need to put something in the nullHack thingy

Comment: I understood that the "new thread because from android 3 u can't make connections in the main thread" means that i must start a new thread, but if u say that onHandleIntent runs on a own thred, well... i try :D